# Gravity Forms: gform_wrapper stays hidden even though JS-scripts load without errors

Tags: multisite, jquery, plugin-gravity-forms

I think this is worthy of a new question but could be wrong.

So I'm using Gravity Forms v2.3.2 on a sub-site (I have a multi-site install but the plugin is NOT network activated) and am able to use non-dynamic forms just fine. However, when I use a form with dynamic fields, the form stays hidden. I can see the form in the inspector, as well as the two script tags that are suppose to toggle the visibility.

My browser debugger doesn't display any JS errors (btw, I'm using jQuery 3.3.1) and I've also made sure that there isn't any CSS overriding the display of the form.

I've also made sure to include the `<?php wp_footer(): ?>` in my page's footer template.

I suspect that the scripts are somehow loading before the form and therefore not finding the form in order to display it.

Hoping I'm just missing something in the settings... worth a shot anyways. thanks in advance!

Comment: This seems the issue is the plugin specific. In my general approaching, update plugin will be the first step. Of course, Opening a ticket on GF forum will help you.

Answer (score 0):

So evidently, I was having jquery conflicts...

I'm loading in a newer version of jquery and had the "load in footer" argument (in the `wp_register_script`) set to true. I also forgot that WordPress loads in a "default" type of jquery library but in the head.

I first tried to "deregister" the jquery lib that was coming from wp-incudes/ with `wp_deregister_script('jquery')` but then got the "jquery is not defined" message. So then I removed the "load in footer" from my `wp_register_script` (because apparently the GF scripts are NOT loaded in the footer like it says it should and actually load in right after the GF DOM elem. ); but I then got a different error which seemed specific to the GF scripts and it read "gf_apply_rules is not defined."

So what I ended up doing was remove the `wp_deregister_script('jquery')` and also remove the "load in footer" argument of my other jquery, which makes it work but makes me uneasy about loading two jquery libraries. I suppose I can remove my newer version and just find a way to update the one coming from wp-includes? Not sure but I think I'm calling it now :)

UPDATE: Here was the issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23786388/js-error-on-gravity-forms#answer-37258518

Basically, GravityForms looks for the dependency with the name 'jQuery' which my version didn't have.